# Remove eval in an existing code

Tags: sh

I am working on an existing shell script code which has `eval`. I feel like that `eval` is unnecessary here and wanted to remove to *avoid* Injection.

Could you please check the code and advise why there is an eval in the code.

```
FILE_PATH=`echo $1 | awk '{ print $10 }' | cut -f2 -d'"'
FILE_PATH=`(eval "echo ${FILE_PATH}")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $1 is something like that `---"~/tttttttt.txt`. 
FILE_PATH will be `~/tttttttt.txt` without eval.

but with eval;

```
FILE_PATH will be /home/user/tttttttt.txt



#!/bin/bash
path='-----"~/tttttttt.txt'
FILE_PATH=`echo $path | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -f2 -d'"'`
echo "${FILE_PATH}"
ls -lart  ${FILE_PATH}
FILE_PATH=`(eval "echo ${FILE_PATH}")`
echo $FILE_PATH
ls -lart  ${FILE_PATH}
```

if run above script, output:

```
~/tttttttt.txt
ls: cannot access ~/tttttttt.txt: No such file or directory
/home/user/tttttttt.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Aug 26 15:54 /home/user/tttttttt.txt
```

Comment: `eval` is considered unsafe *because* it requires you to make assumptions about `$path` that you can't enforce. `eval` will let you expand the `~`, but it will also execute a command if `$path` is something like `rm -rf /`.

Comment: Yes. $1 contains value like $TOP/bin; It has to be evaluate to get the absolute path. My requirement is to eradicate 'eval' command. Is there any alternate for this? I tried all the scenarios in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead ; But no luck